# Sovol SV06 sensorless homing is not functional

Tags: troubleshooting

I just unboxed my Sovol SV06, and it does not appear to home correctly. When issuing the `G28` command through both the screen and Pronterface, it will crash against the X-axis limit switch until I turn off the machine, as shown in the video below.

I have attempted to use Pronterface to issue new `M914` commands, which is the StallGuard sensitivity setting.  I have lowered both the X and Y values to 10, sent the `M500` command, verified the settings were correct with `M503`, and then ran `G28`. The same thing occurred and it does not appear to function any differently.

I have verified that all of the steppers are plugged in, but I have limited functionality to test anything because the machine cannot home correctly. Is there something I am missing? Included below are the results of running `M503`

```
m503
SENDING:M503
echo:; Linear Units:
G21 ; (mm)
echo:; Temperature Units:
echo: M149 C ; Units in Celsius
echo:; Filament settings (Disabled):
echo: M200 S0 D1.75
echo:; Steps per unit:
echo: M92 X80.00 Y80.00 Z800.00 E691.50
echo:; Max feedrates (units/s):
echo: M203 X500.00 Y500.00 Z10.00 E30.00
echo:; Max Acceleration (units/s2):
echo: M201 X500.00 Y500.00 Z100.00 E5000.00
echo:; Acceleration (units/s2) (P<print-accel> R<retract-accel> T<travel-accel>):
echo: M204 P500.00 R500.00 T1000.00
echo:; Advanced (B<min_segment_time_us> S<min_feedrate> T<min_travel_feedrate> X<max_x_jerk> Y<max_y_jerk> Z<max_z_jerk> E<max_e_jerk>):
echo: M205 B20000.00 S0.00 T0.00 X8.00 Y8.00 Z0.40 E5.00
echo:; Home offset:
echo: M206 X0.00 Y0.00 Z0.00
echo:; Auto Bed Leveling:
echo: M420 S0 Z10.00 ; Leveling OFF
echo:; Material heatup parameters:
echo: M145 S0 H185.00 B60.00 F255
echo: M145 S1 H240.00 B80.00 F255
echo:; Hotend PID:
echo: M301 P15.95 I1.30 D48.96
echo:; Bed PID:
echo:echo: M304 P110.38 I6.12 D497.30
echo:; User thermistors:
echo: M305 P0 R4700.0 T94162.0 B4160.0 C0.000000000 ; HOTEND 0
echo:; Power-loss recovery:
echo: M413 S1 ; ON
echo:; Z-Probe Offset:
echo: M851 X25.00 Y-25.00 Z0.00 ; (mm)
echo:; Stepper driver current:
echo: M906 X860 Y900 Z1000
echo: M906 T0 E550
echo:; Hybrid Threshold:
echo: M913 X183 Y183 Z41
echo: M913 T0 E60
echo:; StallGuard threshold:
echo: M914 X10 Y10
echo:; Driver stepping mode:
echo: M569 S1 X Y Z
echo: M569 S1 T0 E
echo:; Linear Advance:
echo: M900 K0.04
echo:; Filament load/unload:
echo: M603 L0.00 U50.00 ; (mm)
```

Comment: You mention a video in your question, but there is no link posted; maybe you forgot.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that the previous post I had found suggested that the sensitivity setting be lowered when it actually needed to be raised.  Setting the two `M914` values to 75 works perfectly.